# Can I use javascript regular expression in php as it is

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I am using a regular expression in javascript and want to do server side validation as well with the same regular expression. Do i need to modify it to make it compatible or will it run as it is.

How to use PHP regular expresion. Please provide a small example.

Thanks in Advance

**EDIT**

For Email Validation

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
```

For Phone no validation

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use one of the following functions [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) or [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php). And with a bit of luck you shouldn't need to modify your regex.
PHP regex uses the classic Perl regex, so a match would look like 
`preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/', $myStringToBeTested, $results);`

Later edit:

```
$string="test@mail.com";

if(preg_match('/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/', $string))
    echo "matches!";
else
    echo "doesn't match!";
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

PHP regexp are based on PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expression).
Example (find digits) :

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]*$/', 'my01string');
```

See [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php).

Javascript regexp are slightly different (ECMA).

```
var patt1 = new RegExp("e");
document.write(patt1.test("The best things in life are free"));
```

See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) for a comparison table.

Answer (score 3):

Supposed to work for most of the patterns, except escaping special characters and backslashes, but not reverse, php regex have features than javascript like look behind expressions.

```
javascript : /[a-z]+/
php        : '/[a-z]+/'
```

For example,

`var pattern = new RegExp(/^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/);`

would be `'/^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/'` in php

Answer (score 1):

In PHP we use the function [**preg_match**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

```
$email_pattern = '/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i';

$phoneno_pattern = '^/\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/';

if(preg_match($email_pattern,$input_email)) {
 // valid email.
}

if(preg_match($phoneno_pattern,$input_ph)) {
 // valid ph num.
}
```

You could have used the regex ***directly*** as the function argument instead of using a variable.