# How to conver Javascript regular expression to PHP regular expression?

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have a regular expression of JavaScript, which is given below

```
/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+|(?:www\.|[\-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/\.\w\-]*)?\??(?:[\-\+=&;%@\.\w]*)#?(?:[\.\!\/\\\w]*))?)/g
```

and I need to use it in PHP, so I need PHP version of this regular expression, any idea please?

Comment: This previous SO question should help you find the way:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621583/can-i-use-javascript-regular-expression-in-php-as-it-is][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621583/can-i-use-javascript-regular-expression-in-php-as-it-is

Comment: I think it will be the same in PHP, nothing different.

Comment: It is not a valid PHP regex.

Comment: It's mostly valid in PHP, apart from the unnecessary flag. Google the error message you're getting but forgot to include in your question.

Comment: It filters URLs in given text, not validate email.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up, it would probably look like this (without the //g modifier)

```
 # '~((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?://)?)(?:[-;:&=+$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www\.|[-;:&=+$,w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:/[+\~%/.\w-]*)?\??(?:[-+=&;%@.\w]*)\#?(?:[.!/\\\\\w]*))?)~'

 (                                          # (1 start)
      (                                          # (2 start)
           (                                          # (3 start)
                [A-Za-z]{3,9} :
                (?: // )?
           )                                          # (3 end)
           (?: [-;:&=+$,\w]+ @ )?
           [A-Za-z0-9.-]+ 
        |  (?: www\. | [-;:&=+$,w]+ @ )
           [A-Za-z0-9.-]+ 
      )                                          # (2 end)
      (                                          # (4 start)
           (?: / [+\~%/.\w-]* )?
           \??
           (?: [-+=&;%@.\w]* )
           \#?
           (?: [.!/\\\w]* )
      )?                                         # (4 end)
 )                                          # (1 end)
```